# Is showing the payment pages using Webview solves the App-store's In-App Purchase issue?

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, app-store

I got a new message from Appstore for my new app submission:

**Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase**

> We noticed that your app or its metadata enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

My app has a payment feature and I have implemented it using stripe.

The payment feature is implemented on sign up, free trial and manage subscription pages. Currently, I have implemented all these features in the app itself. **I have website links for these pages and I can show these pages using a `webview` with the website links. If I do like that, is AppStore approve my app?** I have also removed the `Stripe.net` NuGet package.

Comment: You can read the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase) to get more information about [in-app-purchase](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase) and [goods-and-services](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#goods-and-services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you offer **digital goods & services within your app, you must use in-app purchases** and give Apple their 30% cut.

You cannot use any other method, no matter which technology (webview, link, etc.) or provider (Stripe, PayPal etc.) you are using.

If you offer **non-digital goods & services** (i.e. taxi ride, physical books, etc.), you can use any payment for you seem fit and cannot (!) use in-app purchases.

Comment: Could you please read my answer? You offer digital goods, which always must go through in app purchases. You can never use any other payment gateway.